# GWT custom popuppanel or dialogbox

Tags: gwt

I would like to create popup or dialog box which should be like another window where i need to have cross (*) mark to close window. please any one can suggeston this..

Answer (score 0):

Gwt has a [dialog box](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDialogBox). You add layout panels to it and arrange what you want to show in it.

You can use [custom button](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomButton)
to add your cross.

Comment: Hi Bhat, thanks for reply, i want to create widget like exactly a window,, any other possibilities??

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597726/how-to-add-a-close-button-to-the-caption-bar-of-a-gwt-dialogbox