# GWT Tab panel close

Tags: gwt, tabs

I am building an application in GWT.  I have a decorated tabpanel in
my application.Where in am adding panels to it dynamically.Now i want
to achieve the closing of these tabs. I want to add a close image to
the tab bar and event to that image for closing. I am using UIbinder.

Answer (score 6):

the working code is like that;

```
    private Widget getTabTitle(final Widget widget, final String title) {

    final HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    final Label label = new Label(title);
    DOM.setStyleAttribute(label.getElement(), "whiteSpace", "nowrap");

    ImageAnchor closeBtn = new ImageAnchor();
    closeBtn.setResource(images.cross());

    closeBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            int widgetIndex = tabs.getWidgetIndex(widget);
            if (widgetIndex == tabs.getSelectedIndex()) {
                tabs.selectTab(widgetIndex - 1);
            }
            tabs.remove(widgetIndex);               
        }
    });
    hPanel.add(label);
    hPanel.add(new HTML("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"));
    hPanel.add(closeBtn);
    hPanel.setStyleName("gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab");
    return hPanel;
}
```

In order to add tab,

```
    public void addTab() {
    TabWriting tw = new TabWriting(); /* TabWriting in my case, this can be any widget */
    tabs.add(tw, getTabTitle(tw, "Writing"));
    tabs.selectTab(tw);
}
```

You'll going to need, ImageAnchorClass

```
public class ImageAnchor extends Anchor {

public ImageAnchor() {
}

public void setResource(ImageResource imageResource) {
    Image img = new Image(imageResource);
    img.setStyleName("navbarimg");
    DOM.insertBefore(getElement(), img.getElement(), DOM
            .getFirstChild(getElement()));
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't supported natively in GWT.

You can manually try to add it.

Read this - http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/006bc886c1ccf5e1?pli=1

I haven't tried it personally, but look at the solution by gregor (last one).

Comment: @jay Welcome :) would be nice if you could mark this as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

You kinda need to do something along the lines of this

[GWT Close button in title bar of DialogBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926539/gwt-close-button-in-title-bar-of-dialogbox)

First you need to pass in the tab header when you create the new tab. The header you pass in should have your tab text and also an X image or text label to click on. Then add a event handler on the close object that gets the widget you are adding to the tabPanel and removes it. Here is some inline code that works

```
public void loadTab(final Widget widget, String headingText, String tooltip) {

        HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
        panel.setStyleName("tabHeader");
        panel.setTitle(tooltip);
        Label text = new Label();
        text.setText(headingText);
        text.setStyleDependentName("text", true);
        Label close = new Label();
        close.setText("X");
        close.setTitle(closeText_ + headingText);
        text.setStyleDependentName("close", true);
        close.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.alert("close this tab");
                ClientGlobal.LOG.info("widget : " + tabPanel_.getWidgetIndex(widget));
                tabPanel_.remove(tabPanel_.getWidgetIndex(widget));
            }
        });
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(close);
        panel.setCellHorizontalAlignment(text, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
        panel.setCellHorizontalAlignment(close, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        tabPanel_.add(widget, panel);
        tabPanel_.getTabWidget(widget).setTitle(tooltip);
        tabPanel_.selectTab(widget);
    }
```